# How to query across multiple models in single Django view?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I currently have the following models in my Django code.

```
from django.conf import settings  
import math 
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse 
# Create your models here.
import statistics 
from django.utils import timezone  
from decimal import Decimal 
#import for mail
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage, send_mail
from django.db.models import Q, QuerySet, F, FloatField, ExpressionWrapper, Manager 
from django.db.models.functions import Cast 
from django.db.models.aggregates import Avg
import datetime 
from django.utils import timezone

class Card(models.Model):
    card_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    geography_choices = [('Africa', 'Africa'), ('Asia', 'Asia'), ('Australia', 'Australia'), ('Europe', 'Europe'), ('North America', 'North America'), ('South America', 'South America')]
    geography = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=geography_choices, default='North America')

    type_choices = [('Creature', 'Creature'), ('Spell', 'Spell'), ('New Type', 'New Type'),('Undecided', 'Undecided')]
    card_type = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=type_choices, default='Creature')


class Article(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    body = models.TextField()

    author = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model(),
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
    )

    entry_date_time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-entry_date_time']

    score_choices = [(-5,'-5'), (-4, '-4'), (-3,'-3'), (-2, '-2'), (-1,'-1'), (0,'0'),
    (1,'1'), (2,'2'), (3,'3'), (4,'4'), (5,'5')]
    score = models.FloatField(choices=score_choices, default=0)


    read_through_choices = [(-1, 'Competitive'), (0, 'No Effect'), (1, 'Industry-Wide')]
    read_through = models.IntegerField(choices=read_through_choices, default=0)


    cardvar = models.ForeignKey(Card, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

I am trying to run a search function that searches my articles and a) returns articles whose "cardvar__card_name" matches our query and b) articles whose "cardvar__card_type" matches the type of our query (our query is only a cardvar__card_name) and also the "score" is not equal to zero.

I was able to do part a) alone without issue, however, when I tried to implement part B I ended up getting Server Error 500. I think this is due to my having both the Equity and Article models within the same view. However, I am completely out of my depth as to how to fix this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
class SearchResultsListView(ListView): #new
    model = Article
    context_object_name = 'article_list'
    template_name = 'search_results.html'
    def get_queryset(self):
       query =self.request.GET.get('q')
       card_dict = Card.objects.values('card_type').get(card_name=query)
       results = Article.objects.filter(
        Q(cardvar__card_name__iexact=query) | 
       (Q(cardvar__card_type=card_dict['card_type'] & 
       ~Q(score=0))
       ).order_by('cardvar', '-entry_date_time')
    return results
```

Comment: set DEBUG=True at settings.py so you can get details about that 500 error. Then share the details please.

Comment: I get an exception value: "card matching query does not exist" and it points to the following line card_dict = Card.objects.values('card_type').get(card_name=query)

Comment: So it seems there is not any card in your database, so you should catch that exception. I am updating my answer, check it soon :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a paranthesis at your second `Q()`.

And you need to catch the possible `DoesNotExist` exception. Try this:

```
class SearchResultsListView(ListView): #new
    model = Article
    context_object_name = 'article_list'
    template_name = 'search_results.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
       query = self.request.GET.get('q')
       try:
           card_dict = Card.objects.values('card_type').get(card_name=query)
           results = Article.objects.filter(Q(cardvar__card_name__iexact=query) |
                        (Q(cardvar__card_type=card_dict['card_type']) & 
                        ~Q(score=0))).order_by('cardvar', '-entry_date_time')
       except Card.DoesNotExist:
            results = Article.objects.filter(Q(cardvar__card_name__iexact=query)
                         ).order_by('cardvar', '-entry_date_time')
       return results
```

Comment: so that gets rid of the error but it seems like its only ever showing the "except" clause in the search. I know there are some Cards that are in the database that should show related objects from the card_dict under "try" but its only ever going to the except clause. I really appreciate your help here.

Comment: you are welcome! you should debug it, try printing "request.GET", "query","card_dict" etc. inform me as well!

Comment: I gave you an up arrow and a check. If it doesn't show publicly its due to my "user score" being too low, however I did upvote your comment. I truly appreciate all the help you've given me.

Comment: If instead of this line (Q(cardvar__card_type=card_dict['card_type']), I replace card_dict['card_type'] with a "hardcoded" type i.e. 'Creature' I get the results I am looking for. However, when I use the broader, card_dict method I get a "TypeError" on the line (Q(cardvar__card_type=card_dict['card_type']). Why does this occur? I think it may have something to do with it being a Queryset itself but I'm not exactly sure.

Comment: TypeError should give you more details, like "TypeError foo must be goo". can you give that detail too?

Comment: at a second thought, it might be something due to encoding. can you try replacing it with str(card_dict['card_type']) ?

Comment: Yea, I tried that earlier as well as a few other data types, im still messing around with it hoping to get a solution - despite not being finished I would not even be close to where I am without your help, I truly appreciate it.

Comment: Nevermind, i actually just fixed the issue by rather than having card_dict['card_type'], I used card_dict[0]['card_type'] because card_dict returns a queryset object whose sole member is the dictionary, so we first have to write [0] to get down to the "dictionary level" and then we can actually write 'card_type' as suggested.